# Non annotation type for activation object with descriptor

Tags: osgi, aem, bnd

I am getting error when I deploy mvn project .  Non annotation type for activation object with descriptor (Lcom/xxx/sss/ssss;)V, type xxxxx -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal biz.aQute.bnd:bnd-maven-plugin:5.1.2:bnd-process (bnd-process) on project xxxxxx: Non annotation type for activation object with descriptor

Comment: Did you find the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This means that the signature of an OSGI lifecycle method does not conform to the specification. The log entry should show exactly where in newer versions of BND.

For example, I got this when using a custom Map implementation instead of the java.util.Map<string, string> for the @update lifecycle method.

- Fixed by: https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/pull/4225
- Related: https://github.com/bndtools/bndtools/issues/1283